# Mask layout with rounded corner xml shape

Tags: android, xml, shapes, mask

I have this LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#FFD800"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Text View"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

And I want to mask it with rounded corner, like this:

[image]

I tried to put it in a FrameLayout with another layout with shape.xml on top of it,

But the most I got was:

[image]

or

[image]

I'm looking for a way to use shape.xml background,

But with transparent inside the border, and white color outside.

My shape.xml:

```
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid
    android:color="#FFFFFF">
</solid>

<stroke
android:width="2dp"
android:color="#000000" >
</stroke>

<padding
    android:left="5dp"
    android:top="5dp"
    android:right="5dp"
    android:bottom="5dp">
</padding>

<corners
    android:radius="50dp">
</corners>
</shape>
```

Comment: Do you want to mask the whole layout with round corner xml ? Please post your whole xml layout file code.

Comment: @GrlsHu Yes, I want to mask the whole layout with corner xml. (Added my layout)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a nine-patch with white rounded corners outside, transparent in the middle, ("inverse nine-patch") and put it on top on your LinearLayout. This is a common practice.

Comment: Don't know if it's the best answer, but it's the only one that really works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `<solid>` tag from your shape. Then apply that shape to the background of your `LinearLayout`.

Because the `<solid>` tag specifies the fill color of your shape.
Without that tag the center of your shape will be fully transparent.
So it will look just like a border.

Answer (score 0):

Tried out below xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#4a6176" />

    <padding
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
         />

    <corners android:radius="6dp" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score -2):

make your layout background like this: `android:background="@drawable/shape"`