# Imageview round corners and mask shape via xml do not work in AS 3.0

Tags: android, image, android-layout

Topics checked before creating topic

1. [Mask layout with rounded corner xml shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25762867/mask-layout-with-rounded-corner-xml-shape)
2. [Mask ImageView with round corner background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527467/mask-imageview-with-round-corner-backgroun)
3. [How can I make rounded (circled) ImageView box on Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38662500/how-can-i-make-rounded-circled-imageview-box-on-android-studio?noredirect=1&lq=1)
4. [ImageView in circular through xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105775/imageview-in-circular-through-xml)
5. https://inducesmile.com/android/how-to-make-circular-imageview-and-rounded-corner-imageview-in-android/

I want to apply mask to ImageView like from [pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erKOK.png) to [pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGPpQ.png) but it is **formed of multiple gradients** via  .

At first I was using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners android:radius="36dp" />
</shape>
```

Then added `solid` then tried `FrameLayout` then tried adding library from link 5. None of proposed methods did apply mask. Library was causing errors on

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu
if (id == R.id.action_settings
```

Cannot resolve `menu` and `action_settings.`

How come answers are being accepted but I cannot reproduce it? What am I missing in xml files? Even copy-paste whole ImageView + shape did not help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an ImageView with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-with-rounded-corners)

Comment: no need for any third-party external library: all you need is [RoundedBitmapDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawable.html)

Comment: @pskink how do I use it in xml?

Comment: you cannot - you need to setup RoundedBitmapDrawable in java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution via java only (original idea proposed by @pskink)

```
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
    Bitmap src1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img_port);
    RoundedBitmapDrawable dr1 = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(), src1);
    dr1.setCornerRadius(Math.max(src1.getWidth(), src1.getHeight()) / 10f);
    img.setImageDrawable(dr1);
```

Another simple solution via xml [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-with-rounded-corners/30692466#30692466)
i.e

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="15dp"  />
    <solid/>
</shape>
```

and `ImageView.setClipToOutline(true)` in activity.
Additional note: that does not work with